# Never seen a spider with this pattern before

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Found this spider at work in the Leicestershire area of the United Kingdom. Never seen one with this kind of pattern on its back before so was curious as to what it is. (Size: 2-2.5 inches)

[image]

Comment: Please update with approximate size of your specimen.

Comment: Appears to be some species of *Araneus* (orb weaver)

Comment: It was probaly around 2inches maybe 2 and a half

Answer (score 3):

The depicted spider appears to be a European garden spider [***Araneus diadematus***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araneus_diadematus). The mottling pattern that forms a cross shape is probably one of the more distinctive features, giving these the nickname cross spiders. The distribution for your locale makes sense, based on data collected on these spp: http://srs.britishspiders.org.uk/portal.php/p/summary/s/Araneus+diadematus